# Vue Router access route only from certain page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

After a user has logged in the first time I redirect him to the page *CreateProfile* where he types in all the profile information. Afterwards I want to make this site not accessible anymore, such as if the user types the URL into the browser (e.g. [www.myproject.com/createProfile](http://www.myproject.com/createProfile)).

How can I make sure that only the redirection from my login page has access to the *CreateProfile* page? That is, if the user types in the URL manually he will be redirected e.g. to the 404 page.

Currently my route for *CreateProfile* looks the following:

```js
{
  path: '/createprofile',
  name: 'CreateProfile',
  component: CreateProfile,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (store.getters.getUserStatus == true) {
      next()
    } else {
      next({ name: 'Login' })
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `from` route object in the `beforeEnter` navigation guard to test the previous route location.

For example, check that the `from.name` property is `Login`, which will only be `true` when there has been the redirect you want. (Assuming you don't also provide a `<router-link>` from `Login`):

```js
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
  const isRedirected = from.name === 'Login';
  if (isRedirected && store.getters.getUserStatus == true) {
    next()
  } else {
    next({ name: 'Login' })
  }
}
```